# Azure Data Lake Store as EXTERNAL TABLE in Databricks with multiple PATH?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I am trying to create external tables shown below
Path for the table is dynamic, can external table accept multiple path?

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(BusinessDate string,
StoreNumber string)
 USING csv
 OPTIONS ('DELIMITER' '~', 
PATH "/mnt/raw/2021/08/19/store01.txt,/mnt/raw/2021/08/17/store09.txt")
```

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below steps to create a table using multiple paths from ADLS gen2 account.

**Step1:** You the demo purpose I had created two sample csv files which contains data of employees `data1.csv` files contains three rows and `data2.csv` contains two rows.

**Step2:** Upload both the files to a container named `data` in ADLS Gen2 account.

[image]

**Step3:** Create a table using multiple paths from ADLS gen2 account which is mounted as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE default.employee
(id INT, name STRING, age INT)
USING CSV
LOCATION '/mnt/sampledata/data/*.csv'
```

[image]